# How do I make a new dataframe with data from a previous dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

I have the data shown in the screenshot. I want to create a new panda with the column headers of the cells in the forces column in the screenshot and I want the respective values to be listed in each column. I have tried indexing each variable and creating a new panda but that hasn't seemed to work. Could I get some help?

[image: 1]

I tried indexing and creating a new panda but when i index the variables i get a single value as opposed to a list of values.

Comment: We can't build a test script from an image. Its best to post a script that initializes the dataframe and an attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

one way to this is by filtring your dataframe each time on a specific value for the column Forces:

```
column = df['Forces'].unique()
dict_of_column_value = {}
for col in column:
    dict_of_column_value[col] = list(df[df['Forces'] == col].Values)
pd.DataFrame(dict_of_column_value)
```

Comment: I don't need to transpose it as there are numerous lift cells in the column so they would all create new columns if transposed leading to 1800000 columns when I should only have like 10.

Comment: thank you now i understand better the question i did change the response